# faster compile and editor update in unity

Tags: unity, c#

sometimes for some small changes, I need to recompile the code In the editor and it causes some time to be testable in the editor(sometimes more than 20, 30 seconds).

I know when loading shows on the bottom-right side of the editor in means that it's compiling the code and when it doesn't move it means that it's updating the editor or checking for possible updates.

I need to know is there any way to make it faster? I mean, is there any option to tell unity don't recompile unchanged classes or don't consider all editor classes for changing the editor? or any other technique that makes the process faster?

as I use unit tests in the editor, most of the time is consumed by updating the editor for any added function or changes on them.

Comment: [What do your searches](http://www.screaminggoose.com/blog/2019/2/4/how-i-cut-unity-compile-times-by-75) on [the topic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) tell you [about this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/incremental-script-compilation.1021834/)?

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: @Kevin 2020.x version

Comment: @virtouso That's not helpful. What is the .x? Are you using 2020.1.0? 2020.3.7? Something in between?

Comment: @kevin that should not really matter. I work on different projects on different versions my current is 2019.4.18 other is the 2020 lts i think its 2020.3.6

Comment: @virtouso It does matter because if you don't have the latest version, you don't have the latest bug fixes and performance improvements. For example, a few months ago there was a bug that caused recompile after script changes to take longer and longer each time until you quit and re-launched the Editor. It sounds like you're almost current in 2020, though you're a bit out of date on 2019.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio and have Visual Studio connected as the debugger, this can slow down compile times as well. It was much worse in older versions of Unity (e.g. 5.6) but still makes a small difference in 2019. I'm not sure about 2020.

Comment: @DMGregory i already have assembly separation in my project but when I look, most of consumed time is on editor updating as I make unit test codes in my project, and the list of test functions gets updated after code changes.

Comment: That sounds like a detail that should be included in your question.